# new line in console when I use cin

Tags: c++

I have problem with an C++ exercise.

In the exercise I am supposed to make the user enter a date.

The problem is when I use `cin` the console jumps one line down when I push enter, so that it becomes something like this:

```
Enter date please: 12

/23

/2001
```

instead of: 12/23/2001

Can someone please help me overcome this problem.

Comment: Do you want to read it to string or to three integers or where?

Comment: You could read the entire string as `12/23/2001` and then split it by the `/` char.

Comment: Apart from parsing on `/` as Tudor suggests could you not just read cin 3 times for date, month and year if that is easier for you to code?

Comment: Indeed, use three `cin >> datePart`s and 2 `cin.get()`s

Comment: re tagging it with `homework` tag makes more sense .

Answer (score 6):

You don't say how you use `cin` to read the date. Try this:

```
char ignored;
int day, month, year;
std::cin >> month >> ignored >> day >> ignored >> year;
```

Then, when you run your program, **don't push enter** until you've typed in the entire date.

Answer (score 4):

Robᵩ has a good answer, but I'm going to extend it.  Use a struct, and an overloaded operator, and check the slashes.

```
struct date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, date& obj) {
    char ignored1, ignored2;
    in >> obj.day>> ignored1 >> obj.month>> ignored2 >> obj.year;
    if (ignored1!='/' || ignored2!='/')
        in.setstate(in.rdstate() | std::ios::badbit);
    return in;
}
```

If you have code for [streaming in literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832875/845092), this can be simplified to:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, date& obj) {
    return in >> obj.day>> '/' >> obj.month>> '/' >> obj.year;
}
```

Comment: Interesting thing with the streaming in literals; I never thought about that.