# Reading in a specific format with cin

Tags: c++, formatting, cin

How can i read in a specific format using cin?
Example:-for reading a complex number, I would like the user to enter it as usual:x+yi,
so i want something like this:
cin>>x>>"+">>y>>"i";
But this is giving an error.What is the right way?Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider using `scanf` it might be a better option for reading formatted data.

Comment: Read until newline, then parse internally.

Comment: actually i am using it in overloading the input resolution operator, thats why i need cin

Comment: You need `istream`, not `cin`. And it doesn't matter; read into `string`, *then* parse.

Comment: What about using the [existing complex number class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825768/safer-but-easy-to-use-and-flexible-c-alternative-to-sscanf/9832875#9832875

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution:

```
char plus,img;
double x,y;
cin>> x >> plus >> y >> img;
if (plus!='+' || img!='i')     ...error
```

In "real life" code you build/use a `class complex`, and overload the operator `>>.`

I try it in Ideone: http://ideone.com/ZhSprF

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    char plus{},img{};
    double x{},y{};
    cin>> x >> plus >> y >> img;
    if (plus!='+' || img!='i') 
        cout << "\nError: "<< "x=" << x <<", plus="  << plus <<", y="  << y <<", img="  << img;
    else
        cout << "\nComplex: " << x << plus << y << img;


    return 0;
}
```

stdin:    `3 + 4i`   --> stdout:   `Complex: 3+4i`

stdin:    `1E4L1e3g` --> stdout:   `Error: x=10000, plus=L, y=1000, img=g`

stdin:    `a+3i`   --> stdout:   `Error: x=0, plus=, y=0, img=`

stdin:    `1e3+93E-2i`   --> stdout:   `Complex: 1000+0.93i`

Comment: `1E4L1e3g` will be a proper complex number with your approach.

Comment: This solution does not handle the condition when reading `x` fails, such as reading a letter instead of a number.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I can't understand what you mean. With '1E4L1e3g' we get an error.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews. Sure, it is too simple. But in many cases it correctly flag an error, like when x is a letter.

Answer (score 2):

As per [my answer on a vaguely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832875/845092), parsing with streams is usually a bad idea, but can be done:

I wrote a bit of code that can read in string and character literals.  Like normal stream reads, if it gets invalid data it sets the badbit of the stream.  This should work for all types of streams, including wide streams.  Stick these four functions in a header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>

template<class e, class t, int N>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, const e(&literal)[N]) {
        std::array<e, N-1> buffer; //get buffer
        in >> buffer[0]; //skips whitespace
        if (N>2)
                in.read(&buffer[1], N-2); //read the rest
        if (strncmp(&buffer[0], literal, N-1)) //if it failed
                in.setstate(in.rdstate() | std::ios::badbit); //set the state
        return in;
}
template<class e, class t>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, const e& literal) {
        e buffer;  //get buffer
        in >> buffer; //read data
        if (buffer != literal) //if it failed
                in.setstate(in.rdstate() | std::ios::badbit); //set the state
        return in;
}
//redirect mutable char arrays to their normal function
template<class e, class t, int N>
std::basic_istream<e,t>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<e,t>& in, e(&carray)[N]) {
        return std::operator>>(in, carray);
}
```

And it will make input characters very easy:

```
if (cin>>x>>"+">>y>>"i";)  {
    // read correctly
}
```

[PROOF OF CONCEPT](http://ideone.com/IVW7v).  Now you can `cin` string and character literals, and if the input is not an exact match, it acts just like any other type that failed to input correctly.  Note that this only matches whitespace in string literals that aren't the first character.  It's only three functions, all of which are brain-dead simple.

Answer (score 1):

It would be certainly better to just use `std::complex`.

Here's a pseudocode illustrating my comments:

```
struct Complex { double real, imag; }

istream& operator>> (Complex& c, istream& str)
{
   // read until whitespace
   char C;
   string Buffer;

   enum { READING_REAL, READING_PLUS, READING_IMAG }
   State = READING_REAL;


   C = str.peek();
   while (/* C is not whitespace */)
   {
       // actually read C
       switch(State) {
       case READ_REAL:
           // check if it fits allowed double syntax
           // continue until first double is read
           /* when it is
               c.real = parsedouble(Buffer);
               Buffer.clear();
               State = READ_PLUS;
           */
       case READ_PLUS:
           // accept plus sign
       case READ_IMAG:
           // read 2nd double
       }
   }
}
```

Note that this operation can fail.