# (How to) Input 2 Values at Once using Single 'cin' Statement in a Specific format

Tags: c++, dev-c++, tdm-gcc

Is it possible display an input message as follows?

```
Enter First Fraction:_/_
Enter Second Fraction: _/_
```

Where `_` are Input spaces?

Using some sort of the following code??

```
cout<<"Enter First Fraction: ";
cin>>N1>>"/">>D1;
cout<<"Enter Second Fraction: ";
cin>>N2>>"/">>D2;
```

**OR**

```
cout<<"Enter First Fraction: ";
cin>>N1>>/>>D1;
cout<<"Enter Second Fraction: ";
cin>>N2>>/>>D2;
```

Comment: no you cannot do that. You need advanced interaction with your terminal to do something like that. I bet `ncurses` can do it

Comment: ncurses? what's that?

Comment: I saw this code in another Stack Question..

```    char plus{},img{};
    double x{},y{};
    cin>> x >> plus >> y >> img;
    if (plus!='+' || img!='i') 
        cout << "\nError: "<< "x=" << x <<", plus="  << plus <<", y="  << y <<", img="  << img;
    else
        cout << "\nComplex: " << x << plus << y << img;


    return 0;```


It seems to require the user to enter a '+' in the middle and a '!' in the end... but i tried, it still doesn't work.

Comment: ouh, tabs disappeared in comments. :/

Comment: lemme put that code as a suggested answer..

Comment: code in comments is not readable. If you have a question about code you should post the code in the question

Comment: i added the answer i found in another stack question here.. as a suggested answer.

Comment: if that is the answer then your question is very unclear. When you write "Is it possible display an input message as follows?" then I understand it as if the following two lines should appear on the screen before the user enters something

Comment: Well, it's not possible to do that with C++ in Console. 
And obviously, i can't make it appear step by step like in PowerPoint Presentations. StackOverFlow Developers should probably add this feature. Anyway, sorry for the inconvenience and confusions.

Comment: anything is possible. Seriously, it can be done, just not easily.

Comment: Yeah, but it would be REALLY lengthy and would use statements that the book hasn't taught in the first 2 chapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Solution to my problem just in case anyone else is facing it..
Credits go to @qPCR4vir

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

main()
{   //This program encourages the user to perform a sum of two fractions.
    int N1, D1, N2, D2, N, D;
    char divide{};
    system("cls");

    cout<<"The Format is: 'A/B' & 'C/D'..\n\n";
    cout<<"Enter First Fraction: ";
    cin>>N1>>divide>>D1;
    cout<<"Enter Second Fraction: ";
    cin>>N2>>divide>>D2;
    
    if (divide=='/')
    {
        N=(N1*D2)+(D1*N2);  //Numerator
        D=D1*D2;            //Denominator
        cout<<"Sum of Both Fractions is: "<<N<<"/"<<D;
    }
    else
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"The Correct Format is: A/B & C/D\nWhere these alphabets are Integers..\n\n";
        cout<<"Example: 4/5";
    }

    getch();
    system("cls");
    return(0);
}
```

**Here's the Part of code that Specifies the Format ONLY for '`cin`' Statement.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    char divide{};                  //iota{};
    int x{},y{};
    
    cout<<"Enter Dividion of Two Numbers (A/B): ";
    cin>>x>>divide>>y;              //>> iota;
                
    if (divide=='/')                //&& iota=='i') 
    {
                                    //x=(N1*D2)+(D1*N2);    //Numerator
                                    //y=D1*D2;              //Denominator
        cout<<"The Fractional Form is: "<<x<<"/"<<y;
    }
    else
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"The Correct Format is: A/B & C/D\nWhere these alphabets are Integers..\n\n";
        cout<<"Example: 4/5";
    }


    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Note: This is Simplified/Modified Solution of @qPCR4vir at; [Reading in a specific format with cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901678/reading-in-a-specific-format-with-cin)