# Getting invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::istream&' from expression of type 'int'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, istream

I am trying to create a class that works with rational numbers and performing operator overloading on them. I am having issue on one part of the program, the input stream.

I am supposed to take input in the format "12/8" for example, and it should store 12 into a variable a and then 8 into a variable b.

Here is my code:

```
istream& operator>>( istream& In, Rational& Item )
{
    char division_sign;
    int a,b;

    In >> a >> division_sign;
    if (division_sign != '/' || !In.good())
    {
        In.setstate( ios::failbit );
    }
    else
    {
        In >> b;
        if (b != 0 || !In.good())
        {
        return Item.numerator_ = a, Item.denominator_ = b;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the error I receive:

```
In function 'std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Rational&)':
131: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::istream&' from expression of type 'int'
```

`Line 131` is the `return` statement

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825768/safer-but-easy-to-use-and-flexible-c-alternative-to-sscanf/9832875#9832875

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compilation error you observe is due to the fact that you try to return a value of another type as you've put into the declaration. You need to return `In` and not `b`:

```
return In;
```

You should therefore return the `istream` object reference in any possible branch of the function execution path. That is, put only one such return statement to the end of the function.

Also have a look at [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/1025391) on operator overloading.

Comment: So now I get this error: warning: control reaches end of non-void function

Comment: @Goose: then you should have a look at my second paragraph. If you declare a function to return a certain type, you must ensure that you can always return something of that type.

Comment: I reread your paragraphs and thought about it for a while then "That is, put only one such return statement to the end of the function." after reading that I figured out where the return statement should go. Thanks. Not sure why people downvoted the question though..

Answer (score 3):

There are several things wrong with your code.  First, you
must return `In`, and only `In` as the last thing you do in your
function; `return In;` should be the very last line in the
function, and there should be *no* other return in the function.
Second, you access `division_sign` without having verified that
the input succeeded (and you shouldn't set the `failbit` if the
the input has already failed).

Roughly speaking, something like the following should do the
trick:

```
char separator;
int nominator;
int divisor;
in >> nominator >> separator >> divisor;
if ( in && separator != '/' ) {
    in.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
}
if ( in ) {
    item  = Rational( nominator, divisor );
}
return in;
```

You might want to check the separator before reading the
divisor, so that you don't extract any more characters if it's
wrong.  (On the other hand, you've already extracted a complete
`int`, so it's going to be very difficult for the client to
continue anyway.)