# C++ Read from a txt file and save everything before "|" in a buffer

Tags: c++

Well, It's pretty hard to explain excatly what I want to I'll just give a example.

```
{accbeingused0or1}|{accName}|{accPassword}|{gameName}|{gamePassword}
```

so It'll look like this:

```
0|account123|password123|gamename123|password123
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline Well... that's all.

Comment: Do you want to replace the first part of the string or do you want to read the data from the string?

Comment: @Quention It's not excatly what I was looking for, but still thanks.

Comment: @MikeMB I want to read the data from the string

Comment: Try searching the web and stack overflow for "C++ read text file parse"

Comment: @user3699124: I think getline is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
template< char Ch >
std::istream& Char( std::istream& is )
{
    if( (is >> std::ws).get() != Ch )
        is.setstate( std::ios::failbit );

    return is;
}

struct Data
{
    int acc_used;
    std::string accountName;
    std::string accountPassword;
    std::string gameName;
    std::string gamePassword;
};

std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& is, Data& d )
{
    is >> d.acc_used >> Char<'|'> >> std::ws;
    std::getline( is, d.accountName, '|' );    
    std::getline( is, d.accountPassword, '|' ); 
    std::getline( is, d.gameName, '|' ); 
    is >> d.gamePassword;
    return is;
}
```

Comment: First of all, Thank you very much for trying to help me. 
I've been trying to get it working with your code for about an hour now but I'm stuck and I don't know what to do. 
Can you give me maybe a little bit more support on how to do it excatly like:
Put it in a loop/class,
Open the file: current.txt,
Then put everything in a buffer (acc_used, accountName, accountPassword, gameName, gamePassword)

Also, I'm sorry for being so dumb to this. I'm pretty new to coding, but you probably already realised it :P

Comment: nvm, I figured it out! Thank you very much the code really helped me

Comment: Sorry! There was a typo in the code, fixed it. Glad it helped you, sorry i couldn't reply earlier ://

Comment: Relevent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825768/safer-but-easy-to-use-and-flexible-c-alternative-to-sscanf/9832875#9832875